# How is it correct to deduce significance level of Pearson's correlation from a table?

Tags: p-value, tables, pearson-r

this is a rather elemental question, but any help would be appreciated anyway.

This [webpage](http://www.gifted.uconn.edu/siegle/research/Correlation/alphaleve.htm) gives a method of finding the p-value of Pearson's correlation coefficient, using a table. However, the methods  listed in   [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)  suggest that *using a table* is only valid if the variables are special in some sense, or if there is enough data.

So, my question is: under no assumptions for the random variables for which Pearson's correlation is calculated, is it correct to use a pre-computed table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the early 20th century F. N. David produced tables for the Pearson product moment correlation coefficient when the variables (Y,X) are assumed to have a bivariate normal distribution.  These are probably the tables you are looking at.  If the true correlation is 0 the table provides the sample correlation coefficient's distribution and hence can be used to test the null hypothesis that the correlation coefficient is 0  against the alternative that it is different from 0.
Alternative Fisher devised a transform for the sample correlation coefficient that makes its distribution approximately normal when the true correlation is 0.  So an alternative to the table is to apply Fisher's transform and then use tables of the standard normal distribution to test the hypothesis.

Comment: Hey thanks! What happens if the variables do not have a bivariate normal distribution?

Comment: Then the table doesn't apply.